# Optimising a groupBy Query

Tags: sql, group-by, mariadb, aggregate-functions

I have two tables A and B. A has `id, startDate, endDate`. B has `id, date, count`. The goal is to get the maximum count between `startDate` and `endDate` for each entry in `A`.

```
select a.id, a.startDate, a.endDate, max(b.count)
from A a join B b
  on a.id=b.id
 and b.date>=a.startDate
 and b.date<=a.endDate
group By a.id, a.startDate, a.endDate;
```

e.g.

**A -> (1,2016-01-01,2016-01-03)**

**B -> (1,2016-01-01,1),(1,2016-01-02,4),(1,2016-01-03,3),(1,2016-01-04,2)**

**Query Result -> (1,2016-01-01,2016-01-03,4)** Here 4 is max of (1,4,3)

I have indexes on `id, startDate, endDate` for table `A` and `id, date` for table `B`. The row count in `A` is around 10K while in `B` is 2 million. The above query takes around 5-6s to complete. Can anyone suggest something that I could try out ?

Comment: Please add sample input data as well as expected result.

Comment: "indexes on all necessary columns" is not sufficient. Please state what indexes you have exactly.

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
select a.id, a.startDate, a.endDate, max(b.count)
from A a join
     B b
     on a.id = b.id and
        b.date >= a.startDate and
        b.date <= a.endDate
group By a.id, a.startDate, a.endDate;
```

The place to start is an index on `b(id, date, count)`.  That might help.  However, the query engine is still doing an aggregation over the entire `a` table -- and that is expensive.

Often, a correlated subquery works better:

```
select a.id, a.startDate, a.endDate, 
       (select max(b.count)
        from B b
        where a.id = b.id and
              b.date >= a.startDate and
              b.date <= a.endDate
       ) as count
from A a ;
```

For this, you definitely want the aforementioned index.

Comment: @user3294786 . . . Do you have the recommended index?

Comment: I had the index that you mentioned.

Comment: @user3294786 . . . Interesting.  I would expect the composite index with those three columns in that order to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add these indexes and see which of them is useful (using EXPLAIN):

```
ALTER TABLE `A` ADD INDEX `a_idx_id_startdate_enddate` (`id`,`startDate`,`endDate`);
ALTER TABLE `B` ADD INDEX `b_idx_id_date_count` (`id`,`date`,`count`);
```

Comment: Both of your indexes are being listed in the possible keys column. However only `b_idx_id_date_count` is being used (only one shown in the Key column)

Comment: Did you measure the query performance after adding the indexes? Was it improved?

Comment: There was no improvement. I initially had an index on `id, date`. Adding `count` did not help.